# fixing memory leak with valgrind

Tags: c, memory-management

i built a linked list library and i wrote a clear function which go through the list and free all the memory associated with list. like this:

```
/creating the list
list *myList = (list*) calloc(1, sizeof(list));

//lets try to add a node to the list
list_add_at (NULL, 0, (int*)100);
list_add_at (myList, 0, (int*)100);
list_add_at (myList, 1, (int*)200);
list_add_at (myList, 2, (int*)300);
list_add_at (myList, 3, (int*)400);
list_add_at (myList, 4, (int*)600);
list_add_at (myList, 5, (int*)800);

list_clear(myList);
```

and then when i run the valgrind, it will say that "indirectly lost: 120 bytes in 5 blocks" and this is the number of nodes i added to the list.
my question is how i can free these memory locations i used ?

Thanks

Comment: You are probably doing another `malloc` somewhere.

Comment: Maybe show more of the code..

Comment: Not enough code shown, are any members of the list `malloc`ed? Because you will need to `free` those as well.

Comment: Please show the code that adds items to your list.

Comment: The key to what needs to be de-allocated is in `list_add_at`.

Comment: Converting integer numbers to `int*` look rather suspicious - if possible, you should avoid code like this.

Comment: thanks a lot, i used this code just for testing, can i write another function which goes and clear the 5 blocks after running my clear function "the one i post earlier using while loop" ?

Comment: No, once your clear function has finished, it is too late to free the remaining blocks. You need to free them as you go through the list nodes.

Answer (score 0):

According to [valgrind documentation](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.deflost),

> "indirectly lost" means your program is leaking memory in a pointer-based structure.

In other words, this is an indication that your linked list node has another pointer that you have set to a result of `malloc`, and you have forgotten to de-allocate that memory.

The fix would be to add `free` for the pointer inside the linked list node:

```
while ( temp != NULL ){
        list->head = temp->next;
        free(temp->allocated_ptr); // <<= Free the memory attached to the node
        free(temp);
        temp = list->head;
}
```